# Sending push notifications to different users at device time with FCM

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send a Push notification to different users at different time. The time will be devise time not server time.

For example -

I want to send a push notification to 'Ajay' at 8AM of device time - 'Good Morning Ajay'
I want to send a push notification to 'Gargee' at 2PM of device time - 'Have a wonderful day'

How do I receive the device time before sending the push notification?

Answer (score 0):

You can't schedule notification on mobile side.
Notification messages don't execute your application code when your app is in the background. All messages sent from the Firebase console are Notification messages. So you can't currently use the Firebase console for what you are describing. So, you can send Data messages from your app server which can trigger background execution of code. You can manage the notification scheduling on your app server Using cronjob.

Otherwise, You can write cloud function for notification scheduling...

Answer (score 0):

You can take the support of local notification here. You can either fire local notification or you can use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` to make an API call for saving the device time and also fire the push notification accordingly.